# Tkinter: What widget to use scroll bar with? (currently using Listbox with labels inside)

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I currently have a Listbox with a scrollbar attached but inside the Listbox I have a series of Labels. I would like to be able to scroll down the Listbox when the number of Labels go over the pre-determined Listbox size limit.

I just found out that my way is not possible, but I was wondering if there was another widget that I could use to get around my problem? If not, is there another way of building the contents of the Listbox so that the scroll bar could operate properly?

My code example is written below:

```
from tkinter import *

customerList = [[36218745, 'KER ELIX ULTI CH FINS 100ML US V315', 350, 0, 3474636218745, 1], [36382682, 'NUT BAIN SATIN 2 250ML', 400, 0, 3474636382682, 1], [36397983, 'RES THERAPISTE MASQ 200ML', 550, 0, 3474636397983, 1], [36398850, 'REF CHROMACAPTIVE MASQ 200ML', 550, 0, 3474636398850, 2], [36382668, 'NUT OLEO RELAX MASQ 200ML', 550, 0, 3474636382668, 1], [36397952, 'RES FORCE ARCH MASQ 200ML', 550, 0, 3474636397952, 2], [30458222, 'REF FONDANT CHROMACAPTIVE 1000ML', 800, 0, 3474630458222, 2], [30458062, 'REF CHROMACAPTIVE MASQ 500ML', 950, 0, 3474630458062, 1], [36356003, 'DENSIFIQUE FEMME 30X6ML', 1500, 0, 3474636356003, 3], [30525658, 'SE PRO KERATIN REFILL SHMP 250ML        ', 55, 0, 3474630525658, 2], [26404810, 'HAIR SPA OIL 100ML                      ', 70, 0, 8901526404810, 1], [30641044, 'SE ABS REPAIR LIPIDIUM THER CRM 125ML   ', 85, 0, 3474630641044, 1], [30525870, 'SE PRO KERATIN REFILL COND 150ML        ', 85, 0, 3474630525870, 1], [30640702, 'SE ABS REPAIR LIPIDIUM MASQ 200ML       ', 90, 0, 3474630640702, 2], [30640504, 'SE ABS REPAIR LIPIDIUM SHMP 250ML       ', 90, 0, 3474630640504, 1], [30714946, 'SE VITAMINO COLOR AOX SULFAT FREE 150ML ', 110, 0, 3474630714946, 4], [36202430, 'SE VITAMINO COLOR AOX FRESH MASQ 150ML  ', 115, 0, 3474636202430, 2], [30632196, 'TNA PLAYBALL DEVIATION PASTE 100ML      ', 125, 0, 3474630632196, 1], [36501960, 'MYTHIC OIL HUILE ORIGINAL 100ML         ', 150, 0, 3474636501960, 1], [30643659, 'SERIOXYL THICKER HAIR 90ML              ', 170, 0, 3474630643659, 1], [30633629, 'MYTHIC OIL SERUM DE FORCE 50ML          ', 180, 0, 3474630633629, 2], [36494859, 'REF CHROMACAPTIVE MASQ CX FINS 200ML', 550, 0, 3474636494859, 1], [18251615, 'HAIR SPA NOURISHING MASQ 1000ML         ', 350, 0, 6955818251615, 2], [86130594, 'FIBERSTRONG BRILT MASQ 150ML            ', 90, 0, 884486130594, 1]]

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

frame3 = Frame(frame, bg = "white", width = 690, height = 400, borderwidth = 1)
frame3.pack(expand = True, fill = Y)

frame3Canvas = Canvas(frame3, width = 690, height = 400, bg = "white")
frame3Frame = Frame(frame3Canvas, bg = "white", width = 690, height = 400, borderwidth = 1)
frame3ScrollBar = Scrollbar(frame3, orient = "vertical", command = frame3Canvas.yview)
frame3Canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=frame3ScrollBar.set)

frame3ScrollBar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)

frame3Canvas.create_window((690,400), window=frame3Frame, anchor="nw", tags="frame3Frame")

frame3.bind("<Configure>", frame3Canvas.configure(scrollregion=frame3Canvas.bbox("all")))

frame3Frame.pack(expand = True, fill = Y)
frame3Canvas.pack(side = LEFT, fill = Y)



frame3Label1 = Label(frame3Frame, text = "Bar Code", relief = "ridge", width = 15)
frame3Label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

frame3Label2 = Label(frame3Frame, text = "Product Description", relief = "ridge", width = 30)
frame3Label2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

rowNum = 1
totalCost = 0
totalQuantity = 0
for i in range(len(customerList)):

    barCodeString = str(customerList[i][4])
    frame3BarCode = Label(frame3Frame, text = barCodeString, relief = "ridge", width = 15)
    frame3BarCode.grid(row = rowNum, column = 0)

    prodDesc = customerList[i][1]
    frame3ProdDesc = Label(frame3Frame, text = prodDesc, relief = "ridge", width = 30)
    frame3ProdDesc.grid(row = rowNum, column = 1)

    rowNum += 1


root.geometry("690x350")
root.resizable(False, False)
mainloop()
```

Comment: @Nae added bits of my code

Comment: ok, my bad. WIll try to make a fix for it. Sorry

Comment: @Nae updated again. Kinda encompases what I was looking at with an unusable scroll bar even if it isn't the most minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert widgets into a text widget or a canvas. Both of those have methods for inserting other widgets. You can't use `pack`, `place`, or `grid` for the items you want to scroll, you'll have to use special methods unique to those widgets.

The most common choice is to create a canvas, add a single frame to the canvas, and then you can use `pack`, `place`, or `grid` to put other widgets in the frame. That may be overkill for what you're trying to do. If all you need is a vertical stack of identical labels, a text widget is probably the easiest.

Comment: I have a 2D array of Labels (i.e. x by 6 layers of labels). If i go for the 2nd option you mentioned then with my given program it'd look like masterFrame -> frame3 -> canvas (w/ scrollbar) -> newFrame -> series of labels, correct?

Comment: @Miggy yes, that is one way

Comment: @Oakley Would I have to create_window for Frame in the Canvas config?
If not then do i attach the scrollbar to frame3 and just configure the Canvas (yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set) ?

Comment: @Oakley, I saw that earlier, hence why I was wondering if I'd have to use the create_window config. I'll try playing around a bit more with it to see if I can get it working. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my code above to reflect the changes I made using the post you've linked earlier. Now the scrollbar is movable but is non-functional. Any ideas why?